# Uncaught TypeError: Buffer2 is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt, vite

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Buffer2 is undefined` when I import jsonwebtoken into my react project.

Both `import jwt from jsonwebtoken` and `import {decode} from 'jsonwebtoken'` raise the error.

I am using jsonwebtoken v8.5.1.
I am using vite v2.7.2 as my build tool.

What could be causing the issue?

**Stack Trace**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Buffer2 is undefined
    js index.js:11
    __require chunk-ESTXZSVW.js:12
    js sign-stream.js:2
    __require chunk-ESTXZSVW.js:12
    js index.js:2
    __require chunk-ESTXZSVW.js:12
    js decode.js:1
    __require chunk-ESTXZSVW.js:12
    js index.js:2
    __require chunk-ESTXZSVW.js:12
    <anonymous> jsonwebtoken:1
index.js:11:4
    js index.js:11
    __require chunk-ESTXZSVW.js:12
    js sign-stream.js:2
    __require chunk-ESTXZSVW.js:12
    js index.js:2
    __require chunk-ESTXZSVW.js:12
    js decode.js:1
    __require chunk-ESTXZSVW.js:12
    js index.js:2
    __require chunk-ESTXZSVW.js:12
    <anonymous> jsonwebtoken:1
    InnerModuleEvaluation self-hosted:2374
    InnerModuleEvaluation self-hosted:2374
    InnerModuleEvaluation self-hosted:2374
    evaluation self-hosted:2335
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: @CherryDT added stack trace

Comment: Opened an issue on their Github [#6500](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6500)

Comment: ...hm, now that I looked at it again, I'm thinking that even though there is no `Buffer2` with a `2` in `jsonwebtoken` so that must have been added by Vite, the root cause could be something else entirely - namely that you are trying to use a node.js-only library in the browser! Browsers don't have any global `Buffer` object. Which makes me wonder - why do you even try to use `jsonwebtoken` in the browser? Unless you are trying to build a JWT debugging tool, there is normally no need to interpret a JWT on the client. Almost always you'd send it to some server for authentication...

Comment: I am trying to decode a token that I receive from a server. Weird thing is that I have used the library in another react project (one scaffolded by create-react-app) and it worked fine.

Comment: Maybe there you have a buffer polyfill like [this one](https://github.com/feross/buffer) included? To be honest, I never tried using that library in the browser myself, only on the server. I just arrived at this conclusion based on the fact that `jsonwebtoken` uses `node-jws` as dependency and in some GitHub issues of `node-jws` they talked about that the library uses node-specific core modules that are not available in the browser...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with Webpack dropping support for polyfills. The only reason I found out about it is because I recreated the project in `create-react-app` and it showed me a really helpful error message. Vite just showed me a blank page.

More Details: https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#automatic-nodejs-polyfills-removed

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error. In my case, the problem occurred because I mistakenly tried to import a backend dependency in the frontend code.

If you get this error, rather than installing 'buffer' or making changes in the config file as some people suggest, first, just have a close look at all your recent changes and check for imports :)